# How do you search for single-character symbols in quotes on Google Search?

Tags: google-search

I don't know if it is a bug, but I'm trying to look up a certain video name using Google Search. But Google doesn't show any results if I search for this:

```
site:somesite.com "$"
```

However, if I use:

```
site:somesite.com "$$"
```

Then Google will display results containing the `$$` in quotes. How do I make Google search for a SINGLE symbol in quotes rather than more than 1? Mind you that if I don't include the quotes for `$`, Google will ignore it and only read `site:somesite.com`

Comment: It is not possible. This has been asked and answered before. I might spend time searching that for your later.